# Rating for category

Tags: magento-1.7, category

I would like to create **rating system** for **categories** in Magento 1.7.
I was planning to use rating mechanism from products, but maybe there's different (easier) way?

Maybe someone got solution for that already? Plugin?

Comment: Just a note that product rating requires users to be registered.

Comment: yes, that's fine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to prepare custom module, but looks like there is working solution already:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-review.html

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is the easiest way. The rating system is already made to do what you want.

Just add your entity to `review_entity` and/or `rating_entity`. Then just add the ratings/reviews.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the simplest way would be to base the rating values for the category on the sum of the rating values for all products in that category. Otherwise, yes, just add your own entity as @Fabian suggests.

Comment: Good point, in general that would work and it's very simple to calculate, but in my case I need to create category rating that is not connected with products.